# How to make textbox values unique which are present in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table with data like

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In jQuery

```js
$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("keyup", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function() {
  var j = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  var barcode = $("#barcode" + j).val().trim();
  var barcodeexisting = $("#barcode" + j - 1).val().trim();
  if (barcode == barcodeexisting)
    // do something
});
```

I am trying to tweak the above code for checking that if the barcode which the user has typed should not be same as that of other entered text inside the html table.
I am not able to get any idea how will I do it.

Please help!!!

Comment: This is just for demo... actual html portion is bulky

Comment: Do you mean that you want to compare all the 4 `input`s? or only his "brother"?

Comment: yes i mean all the inputs with id's like barcode0, barcode1,,, Please ignore the corresponding which are hidden by class hide and are used for other purposes,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the input `change` (better than `keyup` because if first barcode is `1`, then it will `alert` for each input which will start with `1`), get all values from the other inputs (using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)) and check if the current value is equals to any of them.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val();
      
  var barcodes = $('input').not($this).map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  
  if (barcodes.indexOf(val) > -1) {
    alert('duplicate');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode1" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb2" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode3" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By the way, `id`s must be unique..

Answer (score 0):

An input field should not have an ending  they should look like this:

`<input type="text" value="" class="">`

I wrote you an example of how you can achieve this by iterating through all other fields when one input is changed to compare duplications.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXKyMr?editors=1111)

Comment: It works fine in ur fiddle. While i try to implement it in the actual code... it does not work.

Comment: Do you have the javascript inside a on load event? You have to make sure the DOM has been loaded before you run that javascript.
Does the table has the class: uniqueBarcodes
To find the problem, a good way is to use console.log() to see what the variables contains. The console.log() will print it in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table').on("keyup", "tr td input[id^='barcode']:not([id^='barcodedb'])", function() {
  var ThisIs = $(this);
  var barcode = $(this).val().trim();
  $("input[id^='barcode']:not([id^='barcodedb'])").not($(this)).each(function(){
    if(barcode == $(this).val().trim()){
      console.log('Duplicated with ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb1" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode1" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```